# Плавный скролл на якорь (скроллит обратно при повторном вызове)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Пытаюсь сделать плавный скролл на якорь при нажатии на ссылку. Но работает не так, как должно.

[По этой ссылке пример скролла](http://dev.wkornilow.org.ua/freshdesign/portfolio/01.html)

Структура сайта такая:

1. Слева sidebar
2. Справа зона контента

Соответственно левая часть статичная, а в правой прокручивается в зависимости от высоты контента.

Для этого в родительский блок `.container` был помещен блок `.child.scrollable`

```
.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.scrollable {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Вроде все просто и банально, но не могу понять, почему ведет себя так переключение между якорями. При нажатии на первую ссылку страница скроллится на нужное место, но при повторном нажатии страница поднимается в начало. И так на всех ссылках.

Если же убрать дочерний блок `.child.scrollable`, то все работает как должно.

[Ссылка на пример](https://jsfiddle.net/afguzLxn/)

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Происходит это по той причине, что `$(scroll_el).offset().top` возвращает позицию элемента относительно окна (а не родителя). Первоначально в данной ситуации элемент имеет некую позицию `x` на странице относительно окна. При первом клике на якорь, `.scrollable` скроллится на расстояние `x`,  и элемент становится на позицию `0` относительно окна. Следовательно следующий клик по этому же якорю отскроллит `.scrollable` к позиции `0`, т.к. отпступ нужного элемента относительно окна уже равен `0`. Получается бесконечный цикл `0` -> `x` -> `0` -> `...`.

Решается это тем, что нужно использовать отступ относительно родителя использованием `$(scroll_el).position().top`, родителем в данном случае выступает контейнер `.scrollable`. Также необходимо учитывать тот факт, что контейнер `.scrollable` собственно скроллится, и позиция элементов относительно его вершины меняется при скролле. Чтобы это исправить необходимо к отступу относительно родителя добавлять также текущее значение скролла родителя `$('.scrollable').scrollTop()`. В итоге выражение по анимации выглядит следующим образом:

```
$('.scrollable').animate({
    scrollTop: $(scroll_el).position().top + $('.scrollable').scrollTop()
}, 500);
```

[Пример на JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ctgg1gf6/1/)

Comment: @wkornilow, а вот этот пример работает верно, в отличии от выбранного вами правильного ответа.