# Прокрутка до якорей с большим body

Tags: javascript, html

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
    elementClick = $(this).attr("href");
    destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
    if ($.browser.safari) {
      $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: destination
      }, 2000);
    } else {
      $('html').animate({
        scrollTop: destination
      }, 2000);
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 300%;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 300%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.container {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 300%;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 300%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
/**/

#a,
#b,
#c {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#a {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #f00;
}
#b {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: #c01;
}
#c {
  left: 200%;
  top: 0;
  background: #df0101;
}
/*center*/

#d,
#e,
#f {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#d {
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
#e {
  left: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  background: green;
}
#f {
  left: 200%;
  top: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}
/*bottom*/

#g,
#k,
#y {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#g {
  left: 0;
  top: 200%;
  background: grey;
}
#k {
  left: 100%;
  top: 200%;
  background: darkgrey;
}
#y {
  left: 200%;
  top: 200%;
  background: lightgrey;
}
#a:before {
  content: "первая страница";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
#b:before {
  content: "вторая страница";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
#c:before {
  content: "третья страница";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
#d:before {
  content: "четвёртая страница";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
#e:before {
  content: "пятая страница";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
#f:before {
  content: "шестая страница";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
#g:before {
  content: "седьмая страница";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
#k:before {
  content: "восьмая страница";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
#y:before {
  content: "девятая страница";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <div id="a">
      <a href="#b">правее</a>
      <a href="#d">ниже</a>
    </div>
    <div id="b">
      <a href="#a">левее</a>
      <a href="#e">ниже</a>
      <a href="#c">правее</a> 
    </div>
    <div id="c">
      <a href="#b">левее</a>
      <a href="#f">ниже</a> 
    </div>
    <div id="d">
      <a href="#a">выше</a>
      <a href="#e">правее</a>
      <a href="#f">правее</a> 
    </div>
    <div id="e">
      <a href="#d">левее</a>
      <a href="#b">выше</a>
      <a href="#f">правее</a>
      <a href="#k">ниже</a>

    </div>
    <div id="f">
      <a href="#c">выше</a>
      <a href="#e">левее</a>
      <a href="#y">ниже</a> 
    </div>
    <div id="g">
      <a href="#d">выше</a>
      <a href="#k">правее</a> 
    </div>
    <div id="k">
      <a href="#g">левее</a>
      <a href="#e">выше</a>
      <a href="#y">правее</a> 
    </div>
    <div id="y">
      <a href="#f">выше</a>
      <a href="#k">левее</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Написал html с большими полями, есть потребность сделать анимированный скролл до якорей, их 9, смысл в том, чтобы было видно куда переадресовывается ссылка. Страница устроена крест на крест и в каждой ячейке (подписано и придан цвет) переход был вверх или вправо, или вниз и куда угодно. Ссылки связаны с якорями, если будет анимированный скролл, то будет очень эффектно. Помогите с js.

Comment: Похож на этот вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453267/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5

Comment: не работает в моём случае ,

Comment: скрол вообще перестаёт работать - у меня во втором примере ( я его не выкладывал сюда ) там просто надо в верх и вниз скролить , то это работает , а там где скролов много - то нет

Answer (score 1):

У Вас в коде было несколько опечаток, следите за своим кодом. Я добавил анимирование свойства `scrollLeft`. Условие `if ($.browser.safari) {` не совсем верное, не только в safari так происходит, в firefox `scrollTop` по  $('html') тоже не работает, универсальным решение будет писать так: `$('body,html').animate({`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
    elementClick = $(this).attr("href");
    destination = $(elementClick).offset();
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: destination.top,
      scrollLeft: destination.left,
    }, 2000);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 300%;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 300%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.container {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 300%;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 300%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
/**/

#a,
#b,
#c {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#a {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #f00;
}
#b {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: #c01;
}
#c {
  left: 200%;
  top: 0;
  background: #df0101;
}
/*center*/

#d,
#e,
#f {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#d {
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
#e {
  left: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  background: green;
}
#f {
  left: 200%;
  top: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}
/*bottom*/

#g,
#k,
#y {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#g {
  left: 0;
  top: 200%;
  background: grey;
}
#k {
  left: 100%;
  top: 200%;
  background: darkgrey;
}
#y {
  left: 200%;
  top: 200%;
  background: lightgrey;
}
#a:before {
  content: "первая страница";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
#b:before {
  content: "вторая страница";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
#c:before {
  content: "третья страница";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
#d:before {
  content: "четвёртая страница";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
#e:before {
  content: "пятая страница";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
#f:before {
  content: "шестая страница";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
#g:before {
  content: "седьмая страница";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
#k:before {
  content: "восьмая страница";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
#y:before {
  content: "девятая страница";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <div id="a">
      <a href="#b">правее</a>
      <a href="#d">ниже</a>
    </div>
    <div id="b">
      <a href="#a">левее</a>
      <a href="#e">ниже</a>
      <a href="#c">правее</a> 
    </div>
    <div id="c">
      <a href="#b">левее</a>
      <a href="#f">ниже</a> 
    </div>
    <div id="d">
      <a href="#a">выше</a>
      <a href="#e">правее</a>
      <a href="#f">правее</a> 
    </div>
    <div id="e">
      <a href="#d">левее</a>
      <a href="#b">выше</a>
      <a href="#f">правее</a>
      <a href="#k">ниже</a>

    </div>
    <div id="f">
      <a href="#c">выше</a>
      <a href="#e">левее</a>
      <a href="#y">ниже</a> 
    </div>
    <div id="g">
      <a href="#d">выше</a>
      <a href="#k">правее</a> 
    </div>
    <div id="k">
      <a href="#g">левее</a>
      <a href="#e">выше</a>
      <a href="#y">правее</a> 
    </div>
    <div id="y">
      <a href="#f">выше</a>
      <a href="#k">левее</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: вообще не работает ! отключился скролл , в том то и геморой что при добавлении ссылки на ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js  перестаёт работать скрол вообще я и noconflict делал и до лампочки , вообще не листает как и в вашем примере "Выполнить код"